# MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error

Tags: ansible

I am trying to create the user account using ansible on Ubuntu20.04. But getting error:

```
msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", 
    "rc": 1
```

But same playbook is working fine for Ubuntu 18.04.
Below is my playbook:

```
- hosts: abc
  remote_user: root
  become: true
  tasks:
  - name: create user account admin with password xyz
    user:
       name: admin
       group: admin
       shell: /bin/bash
       password: $6$pLkiHBvZOf9/zctp1SlLXC2PsTFfwwcwmE73wuwwXb2g8.
       append: yes
  - name: ceating .ssh directory for account admin
    file:
     path: /home/admin/.ssh
     state: directory
     group: admin
     owner: admin
     mode: 0755
  - name: copy authorized_keys file from root
    copy:
     src: /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
     dest: /home/admin/.ssh
     remote_src: yes
     group: admin
     owner: admin
  - name: change the ssh port 
    lineinfile:
      path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
      state: present
      insertafter: '#Port 22'
      line: "Port 811"
      backup: yes
  - name: disable the root login
    lineinfile:
      path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
      regexp: '^PermitRootLogin yes'
      line: 'PermitRootLogin no'
  - name: Restart ssh
    service: name=ssh state=restarted
```

Can you please help me what is the error cause?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can usually get more information from ansible by capturing the error and emitting it:

```yaml
- name: create user account admin with password xyz
  user:
       name: admin
       group: admin
       shell: /bin/bash
       password: $6$pLkiHBvZOf9/zctp1SlLXC2PsTFfwwcwmE73wuwwXb2g8.
       append: yes
  ignore_errors: yes
  register: kaboom

- debug: var=kaboom
- fail: msg=yup
```

and you will get the most information by also running ansible with `env ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 ansible-playbook -vvvv` although often times the extra verbosity still isn't enough to get it to surface the actual exception text, so try that `register:` trick first